# how to get data from different hours at current date in ms sql

Tags: sql-server

how to use select statement in MS-SQL to get data from different hours at current date?

I have a table that has 3 columns: Id, name, dateFinished; the name column will add by different time period. 
For example:

//assume today is 17/05/2016
 
Id= 1, name= A, dateFinished = '17/05/2016 08:00'; 
 
Id= 2, name= A, dateFinished = '17/05/2016 10:00';
Id= 3, name= A, dateFinished = '17/05/2016 12:00';
Id= 4, name= B, dateFinished = '17/05/2016 09:00'; 
 
Id= 5, name= C, dateFinished = '17/05/2016 10:00';
Id= 6, name= B, dateFinished = '17/05/2016 11:00';

//and the records will keep update by name persons when the time pass.

According to the table above, if we check the range between `08:00 to 10:00`. We can see the `Name A` person has two finished times, and `B` person and `C` person only has one finished time.

My point is how to count the amount of the person's dateFinished time in different time range at current date?

//question updated
my desired output table will be:

name-------08AM-10AM(total Finished)-------10AM-12PM
 
A-------2-------1
B-------1-------1
C-------1-------0

and the query must use current date method(ex. GETDATE()), not input string!

If my question is duplicate, please mark as duplicated question and give the related ref.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A has 3 finished time and B two.

Comment: Yes, A has 3 finished time, but A only has 2 finished time on the time period from 08:00AM to 10:00AM

Comment: Please Include what have you try it and what is your desire output

Comment: This is really basic SQL unless there is some aspect to your requirement that you have not communicated clearly enough.   Please google and learn about the `COUNT()` function and `GROUP BY` and `WHERE` clauses in SQL Server

Comment: @TabAlleman I really tought was more complicated at first, maybe some overlaping,  but after write it realize was just basic group by.

Comment: sorry for my unclear questions, it is not just basic group by!

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae3f6/2)**

```
SELECT [name], COUNT([name]) as Total
FROM Table1
WHERE dateFinished BETWEEN '05/17/2016 08:00' AND '05/17/2016 10:00'
GROUP BY [name]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| name | Total |
|------|-------|
|    A |     2 |
|    B |     1 |
|    C |     1 |
```

Comment: your answer is closer, but the total must in every two hours as a column, and it should use GETDATE() method

Comment: @LesterX That is a reason why I would put a downvote, You make a question and didnt specify all the parameters, then I waste my time and wrote an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   name,
   convert(nvarchar(12),
   dateFinished,101) AS [DATE],
   count(name) AS TOTAL 
from 
   **TABLE NAME**
group by 
   name, 
   convert(nvarchar(12),dateFinished,101)
```

OUTPUT

```
    | name | date      | total       
    |    A | 05/17/2016| 2
    |    B | 05/17/2016| 1
```

Comment: Use `ctrl-k` to format the text as code. and try http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm to format your sql text and for output format you have http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly what you're after -- something that looks like this maybe?

```
Name | Date       | 8am | 9am | 10am | 11am | 12pm
A    | 17/05/2016 | 1   | 0   | 1    | 0    | 1
B    | 17/05/2016 | 0   | 1   | 0    | 1    | 0
C    | 17/05/2016 | 0   | 0   | 1    | 0    | 0
```

...

Here is a way to get that:

```
SELECT 
   myName, 
   myDate, 
   [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
           ID,
           Name as myName, 
           Convert(varchar,date_finished,112) as myDate, 
           DATEPART(HOUR, date_finished) as myHour 
        FROM 
           Production.Product
    ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (
       COUNT(ID)
       FOR myHour IN ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is worked for me. BTW, Why I am getting down vote every time when I ask questions?

Comment: one more question, how to use GETDATE() instead of date_finished

Comment: @LesterX You need to improve the way you make your question. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Try create a sample in http://sqlfiddle.com

[**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)